# Is there a way to register new users with Django registration templates that would prevent them from logging in until admin has manually reviewed?

Tags: django, authentication

I'm working on login/registration views in Django in a project that requires that the admin manually reviews the application before the user can actually login...while saving the information they provided at the registration page.

In the past I didn't have projects that required the users be reviewed manually by the admins.

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save()
            login(request, new_user)
            return index(request)
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, "registration/register.html", {"form": form})
```

This is what I would normally write...but even if I don't include the login(request, new_user), the new_user would be able to do so himself after the new_user is created...

I need to make sure they still can't login until the admin has manually reviewed his application to join.

Comment: just set `is_active` to `False` and let the admin change the value to `True` once admin is done with the review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django has a semi built in way to do this. Use `user.is_active`, assuming that you are using the default authentication backend (you almost certainly are if you aren't sure what that is).

```
new_user.refresh_from_db()
new_user.is_active = False
new_user.save()
```

Just add these three lines after `new_user = form.save()`

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save()
            new_user.refresh_from_db()
            new_user.is_active = False
            new_user.save()
            return HttpRequest("Thank you for signing up. Your account is pending review.")
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, "registration/register.html", {"form": form})
```

Administrators can login to the Admin site and manually approve the user by changing the `is_active` element.